# "Cannot call method 'getColumns' of undefined " on FiltersFeature of LiveSearchGridPanel ExtJS

Tags: filter, extjs4.2, gridpanel

im getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getColumns' of undefined when clicking on the header toolbar of a Live Serach Grid Panel on ExtJS. Im implementing filters with the Filters Feature.

Heres some of my code:

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel'
...
]);

var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: false,
    local: true  
};

var grid = new Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    store: store,
    columns:[
    {
        header: "Evento",
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        dataIndex: 'RH_DESCRIPCION',
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    }],
    features: [filters]
 ...
```

This is the block of code where the exception occurs:

```
Ext.Array.each(grid.columnManager.getColumns(), function (column) {
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getColumns' of undefined
        if (column.filterable === false) {
            filters.removeAtKey(column.dataIndex);
        } else {
            add(column.dataIndex, column.filter, column.filterable);
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing heavier debugging it seems that `grid.columnManager` isn't very well supported on  version 4.2. For any others with the same issue you should use:

```
grid.down('headercontainer').getGridColumns();
```

or

```
grid.down('headercontainer').getVisibleGridColumns();
```

to get a hold of columns on your grid. I believe this won't work with grouped columns, I've not tested it though.

Comment: To get all columns, including grouping and hidden use - grid.down('headercontainer').getHideableColumns();

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.Array.each(grid.columnManager.getColumns(), function (column) ...
```

change to

```
Ext.Array.each(grid.columns, function (column) {
```

it works well :)

Comment: In ExtJS 4.2.1 columnManager.getColumns() ignores hidden columns. Also ColumnManager is a private class. I strongly recommend not to use this method. Use myGrid.query('gridcolumn') instead.

Answer (score 0):

grid.columns is not a supported/public property. It might not contain, for example, columns added with reconfigure. It will contain them if you use 4.2.0, but not in 4.2.1/4.2.2. This will happen even if you add Ext.selection.CheckboxModel, the checkbox column will not be included there in 4.2.2 and you will end up with "index mismatch" if you get the index from, lets say cellClick event.

Unfortunately, grid.columnManager or grid.getColumnManager() is new in 4.2.1/4.2.2 and it is a private property/method. Shortly speaking, either of those might stop working with next releases of ExtJS, and "columns" property is not reliable in all cases.

See some discussion here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?277525

I haven't found any officially supported solution yet. I can't add comments, so I had to publish this as a full answer, thanks S.O.!

Answer (score 0):

As others already posted, you should not use the `columnManager` property. Check Sencha's note about it:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnManager

> This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework.
>   Don't rely on its existence.

I think the best option is to use this for all columns:

```
grid.headerCt.getGridColumns()
```

And this if you only need the visible columns:

```
grid.headerCt.getVisibleGridColumns()
```